# Regular expressions: exclusion in character class

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, regex-negation

I want to match an alphabet range between a and z, except x.

I am using `java.util.regex` API for this.

My pattern:

```
[a-z^x] // here a-z shows a range between a to z and ^ means negation
```

**Example**

- If I type "a", it should match.
- If I type "x", it shouldn't match

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add the code which isen't working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your `Pattern` as follows:

`[a-z&&[^x]]`

**Example**

```
String[] test = {"abcd", "abcdx"};
//                         | range
//                         |   | and
//                         |   | | new class excluding "x"
//                         |   | |    | adding quantifier for this example
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z&&[^x]]+");
for (String s: test) {
    System.out.println(p.matcher(s).matches());
}
```

**Output**

```
true
false
```

Comment: @Siddharth you're welcome.